# Regex alphanumeric with special characters

Tags: regex

I need to validate input string using regex which should met below requirements:

- If All Numbers -> Error
- If All Special Characters -> Error
- If only Numbers + special Characters -> Error
- Remaining all should be flagged as non error.

I couldn't get all my test cases passed.

Here is my regex:

```
\d*([a-zA-Z,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][\d,\/().]*)[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$
```

For the special characters, I get a specific list `,\/().` to let them in. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(?:[\d,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d,\/().]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzC4kQ/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[\d,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d,\/().]*)?` - an optional sequence (it lets the string be empty):

  - `[\d,\/().]*` - 0+ digits and special
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - one alpha
  - `[a-zA-Z\d,\/().]*` - 0+ alpha, digits and special
- `$` - end of string

Comment: This is working and thanks. I am just trying to understand & compare it with my regex. In my regex, it is taking all special characters irrelevant to the ones i passed on. Is there anything am missing?

Comment: You are missing `^` (a critical mistake here), and you also allowed whitespace with `\s`.

Comment: If we allow whitespace, then would it be  "^(?:[\d,\/().\s]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d,\/().\s]*\s*)?$ "?   For Ex: It should allow (19 xxxx sjnfjfb)

Comment: Yes, but if you treat whitespace as the special chars, you will need to put `\s` into both `[\d,\/().]` and `[a-zA-Z\d,\/().]`. Best regards.

Comment: what if i dont want the string to be empty?

Comment: @rose The optional non-capturing group encapsulating the consuming pattern part makes it match an empty string. So, you need to remove it and just use `^[\d,\/().]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d,\/().]*$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzC4kQ/22).

Comment: thank you, i have used like this to include alphanumeric _*
"^([\\d,\\*\\_\\s]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\d,\\*\\_\\s]*)\$" is it correct

Comment: @rose I do not know your exact requirements, so it can be correct if it does what you need. You should not escape `*` inside a character class and you must never escape `_`.

Comment: i tried but it didnt work for me. i am using groovy

Answer (score 0):

Going strictly by your requirements, the following would do:

```
[^\d,\\\/().]
```

which matches if there is any "triggering" character (non digit, non special)

If you want to match the whole string, use

```
^.*[^\d,\\\/().].*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all scenarios..

**/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[*@.#&+-])[A-Za-z0-9*@.#&+-]{8,}$/**

Here is how it works,

^(?=.*\d) - checks for at-least one digit in string 

(?=.*[a-z]) - checks for at-least one lowercase in string 
(?=.*[A-Z]) - checks for at-least one uppercase in string 

(?=.*[_@.#&+-]) - checks for at-least one special character in string 
{8,} - checks the string length for a minimum of 8 characters

---

Click here to test it out at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).